# Did Einstein steal another mathematician's work?

Tags: albert-einstein

I saw and information somewhere that Einstein was working at patent bureau and stole a work of some mathematician (relativity theory probably).
Are there any proof?

Comment: If he had, it would be universally known by now. "One doesn't just **steal** an *annus mirabilis.*"

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: I have to downvote questions that include the phrase "I saw" without a source.  Did you see this in a credible document? Or in the Fortean Times?

Comment: Einstein had no qualms about giving credit and being public about his asking help when he got into mathematical trouble. The best example is perhaps his known quote to Grossman, an expert Geometer: “Grossmann, you must help me, or else I’ll go crazy!”, you may be interested to look at: https://www.cantorsparadise.com/the-einstein-grossman-collaboration-4f3ab1946564

Answer (score 1):

He did work in a patent bureau.

He did not steal his achievements there: Theoretical physics is published in journals, not patented.

For sure not the whole structure of General and Special Relativity was his brainchild alone. There were others who worked on related ideas before him (Poincare, Lorentz), and there were those who helped him with the math (Hilbert, Minkowski)

And it seems that he worked closely with his wife and often failed to [credit her properly](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/guest-blog/the-forgotten-life-of-einsteins-first-wife/).

Nevertheless, much was undoubtedly original in Einstein's work.